# How can Integer have an instance of Enum? toEnum and fromEnum only use Int, which is limited

Tags: haskell

I don't fully understand why this works just fine:

```
[9223372036854775809..9223372036854775815] :: [Integer]
```

Those are integers that are larger than `maxBound :: Int`. Yet these are the type signatures of the two crucial `Enum` functions:

```
toEnum :: Int -> a
fromEnum :: a -> Int
```

As you can see, they have `Int`, which is bounded.

So why did the above work?

**Clarification:**

The point of my question is this: Isn't `enumFromTo` defined in terms of `toEnum` and `fromEnum`? And since those two work only on regular `Int`s, how can `enumFromTo` (for which `..` is a syntactic sugar) work for `Integer`s?

Comment: haoformayor answers this question perfectly, but I figured I should mention that `Enum` is, at its heart, a class that tries to do at least three different things, and doesn't do any of them well. Look not to `Enum` for good class design!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`enumFromTo` for `Integer` is not defined in terms of `toEnum` and `fromEnum`, which indeed would cause a loss in representation as you mentioned. You can read the [implementation here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#line-655), which calls `enumDeltaToInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]`.

```
instance  Enum Integer  where
    succ x               = x + 1
    pred x               = x - 1
    toEnum (I# n)        = smallInteger n
    fromEnum n           = I# (integerToInt n)

    {-# INLINE enumFrom #-}
    {-# INLINE enumFromThen #-}
    {-# INLINE enumFromTo #-}
    {-# INLINE enumFromThenTo #-}
    enumFrom x             = enumDeltaInteger   x 1
    enumFromThen x y       = enumDeltaInteger   x (y-x)
    enumFromTo x lim       = enumDeltaToInteger x 1     lim
    enumFromThenTo x y lim = enumDeltaToInteger x (y-x) lim
```

Comment: @haskellHQ oops. fixed.

Comment: **but** [Haskell Report (6.3.4 The Enum Class)](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4) says: `enumFrom` and `enumFromThen` should be defined with an implicit bound, thus...  *smth. wrong?*