# Why does Enum require to implement toEnum and fromEnum, if that's not enough for types larger than Int?

Tags: haskell, enums, functional-programming, typeclass, bounded-types

It is actually just a curiosity, but here's how I came up with it.

##### tl;dr

I could have wondered how to write a sensible `Enum` `instance` for a type larger than `Int`, say `(Int, Int)`.

##### A bit longer

But actually I was wondering: why does `Enum`'s minimal definition assumes that the possible values of `Int` are enough to enumerate the type of which I want to write the `Enum` class?

At [`fromEnum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum) I do read that

> Convert to an `Int`. It is implementation-dependent what `fromEnum` returns when applied to a value that is too large to fit in an `Int`.

which I interpret as saying that I *can indeed* define an `Enum` class for a type that doesn't fit `Int`. I just have to accept that I'll have to return nonsense form `fromEnum` for some values of my type.

But how could `succ` and `pred` possibly work with such a broken type, given [their implementations](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#succ) use `toEnum` and `fromEnum`?

```hs
    succ = toEnum . (+ 1) . fromEnum
    pred = toEnum . (subtract 1) . fromEnum
```

Or maybe I should define manually `succ` and `pred` so that they don't make use `toEnum`/`fromEnum`?

But if that's the case, then way isn't `succ`&`pred` a minimal definition?

Yes, I have read the comment from [dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119428/how-can-integer-have-an-instance-of-enum-toenum-and-fromenum-only-use-int-whic), and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35119484/5825294), but the question remains as to why I need to define `fromEnum`/`toEnum`.

---

##### The origin of the question (in case you have spare suggestions)

I was using [`Word32`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Word.html#t:Word32), but then it took me quite a while to undertand the reason of a but in my program. Essentially, quite a good chunk of my logic was assuming that the value of `Word32`s is not `0`.

Therefore, I thought of using a more appropriate data type implementing appropriate `class`es. I came across [`Integer.Positive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-types-0.1.4.0/docs/Integer-Positive.html), but that's only [`BoundedBelow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-types-0.1.4.0/docs/Integer-BoundedBelow.html#t:BoundedBelow), not [`Bounded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded), whereas `Word32` is `Bounded`, so I decided to write a `data`type myself and came up with a module like this:

```hs
module Positive32 (Positive32, positive32, getNum) where

import Data.Word (Word32)

newtype Positive32 = Positive32 { getNum :: Word32 } deriving (Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Bounded Positive32 where
  minBound = Positive32 1
  maxBound = Positive32 (maxBound :: Word32)

positive32 :: Word32 -> Positive32
positive32 0 = error "Attempt to create `Positive32` from `0`"
positive32 i = Positive32 i
```

so that

```hs
λ> minBound :: Positive32 
Positive32 {getNum = 1}
λ> positive32 2
Positive32 {getNum = 2}
λ> positive32 0
Positive32 {getNum = *** Exception: Attempt to create `Positive32` from `0`
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ......
```

However, soon I realized that, even though I have not exported `Positive32`'s constructor, I can still create `Positive32 0` via its derived `Enum` instance:

```hs
λ> pred $ minBound :: Positive32 
Positive32 {getNum = 0}
```

Hence I tried to write the `Enum` instance myself, think it would have a minimal definition [`succ :: a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ) and [`pred :: a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pred), but in reality it requires [`toEnum :: Int -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:toEnum) and [`fromEnum :: a -> Int`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum).

Now, in my specific usecase, that poses no problem, because `Word32` fits in `Int`, so I can't possibly overflow `Int` with `Word32`, but I'm still left puzzled with the question of why I can't have an `Enum` for types that have more possible values than `Int`.

Comment: Yes, I think the `fromEnum` and `toEnum` are not a good idea, because it maps to `Int`, but there are some other bad things about `Enum`s, for example for `Double` (and other floating point numbers), it does not return the next representable `Double`, but one plus, so `[1.1 .. 5]`, will return `[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1]` for example. The `Enum` is imho a bit of a misfeature.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I think it's quite reasonable to define that `[1 .. 5 :: Double]` is `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]`. If you do that then `[1.1 .. 5]` would pretty much have to be `[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1]` for consistency (or perhaps disallowed for `5` not actually being a valid endpoint?). But `succ == (+1)` is very dubious for `Double`. So IMHO it's more that the fundamental concept of "enumerable" is not the same as the much more pragmatic concept of "supports range syntax". I wouldn't want to actually change `[1 .. 5 :: Double]` to produce the vast number of valid Doubles between 1 and 5.

Comment: @Ben: well if these are "ranges", then`[1.1 .. 4.2]` should normally generate all representable `Double`s. Another problem is for floating points that for large numbers eventually *n* and *n+1* will get the same representation, and so it is possible it keeps repeating the same value either for a large number of times, or even never gets out of the infinite loop. Probably the main concern is that the `Enum` assumes some sort of "linear" shaped structure, but floating-point numbers have more a logarithmic scale. So they are not a "perfect" fit (maybe a *good* one, but definitely not perfect).

Comment: Perhaps the best solution was to not make `Double` an instance of `Enum`. That has indeed drawbacks, but it would imho, make the instances more consistent.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I just think that "a list of every representable `Double` between two points" is much less frequently useful than "a list of `Double`s counting in integer increments between two points", so if I can only have syntax for one I'd rather it be the latter. If there's no explicit step, then it has to defaulted to *something*, and I'm perfectly fine with it being a default step of 1 to be consistent with the numerical difference of range syntax on integers, rather than the default being the next possible value to be consistent with range syntax on enumerations.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem "Floating point types shouldn't have `Enum` instances at all" is a perfectly defensible position though.

Answer (score 7):

I will wax a little philosophical here, as you're asking a question about the motivations of people writing a spec about three decades ago, which from what I know of human memory, may not even be accurately known to the people that were involved themselves.

But: I don't think, at the time Haskell was being defined, there was a really good picture of whether it would catch on at all or merely be a flash-in-the-pan academic curiosity. There are a number of things in the design that are, therefore, pragmatic decisions made for simplicity of the compiler writers and/or the folks writing essentially toy applications. Certainly nothing was being done at the scale of modern, industrial software engineering. I won't talk about all the decisions that I think differ between those two regimes, but certainly typeclass philosophy is a bit different.

At small scales, large type classes (i.e. classes that encompass multiple concepts and have many methods) are very convenient, in the sense of low boilerplate. Type signatures can be more compact; instance implementations have lighter overhead; more library functions in terms of those classes can be provided; functionality can be more easily shared between method implementations; and programmers don't need to keep track of as many concepts.

Of course, we now know there are also costs to this. When you have a wide variety of data types floating around in your application or in publically available libraries, you find that the larger your typeclass is, the fewer types can instantiate it. At small scales, this matters less, because you can simply export the functionality your type *does* support and leave it at that. But at large scales, modularity demands that some behaviors be typeclass-polymorphic, and so types that cannot implement those classes lose out on a lot of already-written functionality.

We've seen this play out repeatedly over the history of Haskell. The introduction of `Applicative` as a stepping stone between `Functor` and `Monad` is one example; splitting `Monoid` out to have a `Semigroup` superclass is another; losing the `Eq` superclass on `Num` also goes on the list. More generally, I think the closer to the core libraries you are, the more important it is in today's designs that typeclasses be split into as many orthogonal pieces as you can. (Of course, you have to know what orthogonal pieces are useful! It's not at all clear that `Applicative` could reasonably have been identified as a useful building block back when making `IO` a monad was a fresh, exciting insight.)

And so we come to `Enum`. In practice, `Enum` serves a variety of roles, including as a de-facto part of the FFI, where `toEnum` and `fromEnum` are often used for marshalling to C; iterating over numeric ranges; listing inhabitants of your favorite type; as the target of multiple forms of syntactic sugar; and likely more besides. With a modern design, these concerns would likely each be split out into its own class with its own concerns and requirements. But at a small scale, most types that support one of those support essentially all of them, and so it's convenient to lump them together and share implementation work and programmer mindspace.

And if you think `Enum` is bad, wait until you start thinking carefully about the numeric hierarchy...

Comment: With `Enum`, the problem is worse than with all the other examples: it not only is "too big", it actually does multiple things that aren't even really compatible with each other. By contrast, though `Num` isn't exactly structured in the most mathematically sensible way, it has generally consistent behaviour. ...Well, at least it had before people [started](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) [abusing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) [it](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.20.2/docs/src/Numeric.Vector.html#line-71) for vectors.

Answer (score 2):

A set of methods being listed as a minimal definition means that the other methods all have default definitions in terms of the minimal set. But the other methods are still part of the typeclass, not separate functions, you certainly can provide your own definitions. Indeed it's reasonably common to see a redundant method provided as a typeclass method *specifically* on the grounds that a (non-minimal) instance may want to override it. For example [`mconcat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mconcat) is documented as:

> Fold a list using the monoid.
>
> For most types, the default definition for `mconcat` will be used, but the function is included in the class definition so that an optimized version can be provided for specific types.

But another thing that can happen is that the default definitions are based on *assumptions* about the behaviour of the minimal set. If you implement the minimal methods in a way that violates those assumptions<sup>1</sup>, then the default definitions of the other methods will not work and you'll have to actually implement them yourself. A documented "minimal definition" for a class is not claiming that you will *never* need to implement the other methods.

(Ideally these assumptions would be clearly spelled out in the class' documentation; this is just one more way that `Enum` is not an ideal class)

`succ` and `pred` can't be a minimal definition for `Enum`, because you can't implement `toEnum` and `fromEnum` in terms of just `succ` and `pred` (okay you could try if you also had `minBound` and `maxBound`, but it would be *awfully* inefficient to figure out that `fromEnum $ Positive32 4000000000` must be `4000000000` by counting how many times you had to apply `succ` to get there from `minBound`... and it would probably produce `3999999999` since your `minBound` is supposed to be `Positive32 1`). Whereas you *can* provide default definitions of `succ` and `pred` in terms of `fromEnum` and `toEnum`, **if** you make some assumptions.

---

<sup>1</sup> You normally should not violate any type class laws in your instance, and for some classes what the default definitions assume about the minimal is *only* that the typeclass laws will hold. In that case any lawful minimal instance will be fine. In other cases the default definitions assume *more* than the typeclass laws, so there are valid instances where the minimal set is not correct without also replacing the defaults for the other methods. `Enum` is a fairly lawless class (its docs don't specify any requirements at all unless the type is also `Bounded`, and even then they don't require a whole lot) and the default definitions make some quite strict assumptions, so it falls into the latter category.

---

In this case the assumption that `Enum`'s default definitions rely on is essentially that if you convert to `Int` with `fromEnum` and then do the equivalent operations using the `Enum Int` instance and convert the results back with `toEnum`, you'll get the same thing you would have got if you implemented them more directly. It's not just `succ` and `pred`; for example this is the [default definition of `enumFromThenTo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#enumFromThenTo) (which is used for the `[x1, x2 .. xn]` syntax):

```
enumFromThenTo x1 x2 y = map toEnum [fromEnum x1, fromEnum x2 .. fromEnum y]
```

This assumption can seem convenient when it holds. It means that in `[x1, x2 .. xn]`, the delta between `x1` and `x2` can be calculated using `Int` subtraction, which can then be repeatedly `Int` added to `x1` and compared to `xn` using `Int` ordering. Without those handy `Int` operations (if `enumFromThenTo` could only be implemented in terms of `succ` and `pred`) then any delta range would essentially have to step through the entire type one step at a time instead of in jumps of the delta, which would be much less efficient.

But this assumption is **really** hard to strictly meet. Even something as simple as your `Positive32` being a `newtype` where `Positive32 0` is intended to be invalid breaks the default method assumptions. It even makes the defaults violate one of the few laws `Enum` has; `pred minBound` is required to be a runtime error, so you *must* override the default `pred` with one that checks that it isn't doing `pred (Positive32 1)`. But then you'll also find that `[Positive32 5, Positive32 4 ..]` won't correctly stop at `Positive32 1` (because it uses `enumFromThenTo @Int`, which has no idea about the `minBound` of your custom type). So you have to override that method too, and so on. (It also won't respect your `maxBound` on platforms where `Int` is larger than 32 bits, and when `Int` is only 32 bits it won't be able to properly enumerate ranges above the `maxBound @Int`)

In fact these defaults are pretty useless. They *look* like they're intended to simplify derived instances for enumeration types (whose constructors have no fields), since the compiler assigns them a nice contiguous range of `Int` where `succ` and `pred` can just be `+1` and `subtract 1`. But of course these types are almost always `Bounded` and (much) smaller than `Int`, so the default `enumFrom` and similar wouldn't even work for these! And indeed if you dump the derived instances for something simple like:

```
data Foo = A | B | C | D | E | F
  deriving (Eq, Show, Bounded, Enum)
```

You'll see that it doesn't make use of all the default method implementations. It generates constants like:

```
$maxtag_Foo_a1Fu :: GHC.Types.Int
$maxtag_Foo_a1Fu = GHC.Types.I# 5#
```

so that it can make use of them in generated non-default `enumFrom` and `enumFromThen`. It does use the default `enumFromTo` and `enumFromThenTo`, since the user-supplied stop value must be something that's in range, so there's no danger stepping outside the valid range provided the `Int` values corresponding to the type are contiguous. If you use non-contiguous or out-of-order `Int`s you can get very bogus results, for example:

```
data Foo = A | B
  deriving (Eq, Show)


instance Enum Foo where
  fromEnum x = case x of
    A -> 1
    B -> 10
  toEnum x = case x of
    1 -> A
    10 -> B
    n -> error $ show n <> " is out of range"

main :: IO ()
main =  do
  -- prints 10, without error
  print $ length [A .. B]
```

Essentially just about the only type for which you could *actually* write a minimal instance defining only `fromEnum` and `toEnum` is... `Int`. Anything larger or in a different order will have range syntax that sometimes errors out or produces incorrect results. For anything smaller and `Bounded`, the defaults will break the laws. (Technically if your type doesn't implement `Bounded` despite being smaller than `Int`, then it's "okay" that `[x..]` eventually produces an error when it steps out of range, since it's only required to stop cleanly if the type is `Bounded`... and you could even argue that *all* the dodgy behaviour is allowed if your type is not `Bounded` since there are no laws at all for `Enum` then, but ugh). Even `Enum Word` can't use the minimal instance, despite `Word` being exactly the same size as `Int` (it's isomorphic to `Int`, but the isomorphism isn't `fromEnum`/`toEnum`), because if it enumerated via `Int` it would have problems with upper half of `Word` that is past `maxBound @Int`.

If your type is smaller than `Int` but maps to a contiguous range then you can at least use *some* of the defaults, but you still need to implement most of the methods. If your type's mapping to `Int` is out of order or has holes, then you're completely out of luck.

But there is nothing stopping you from implementing more than just `fromEnum` and `toEnum` to make your type support range syntax properly. As we've seen, the compiler even needs to do this itself just to properly generate instances for simple enumeration types. If your type is larger than `Int`, then `fromEnum` will necessarily be partial (or fail to round trip with `toEnum`); but if your type is *smaller* than `Int` then `toEnum` is necessarily partial, so if that's acceptable then a partial `fromEnum` that you simply never use should be just as acceptable. Either way, the few typeclass laws `Enum` has don't forbid this situation, so you certainly *can* have an `Enum` instance for a type larger than `Int`.

To be opinionated: `Enum` is simply not a class designed to the standards we would use today (for the reasons that Danial Wagner's answer discusses; it wasn't necessarily a bad choice in the historical context it was actually made in, but the result is bad today). I tend to think it is best approached purely as a weird form you need to fill out in order to get range syntax working, rather than as actually representing the abstract concept of enumerability.<sup>2</sup>

With correctly defined `Enum` instances all the range syntax works well and predictably (well, apart from some dubious behaviour with floating point numbers). Any behaviour that isn't observable through the range syntax I usually treat as meaningless implementation detail that is accidentally exposed, which I try to avoid depending on. Thus I don't care whether `fromEnum` is partial because `Int` isn't big enough; converting to `Int` is just an implementation detail of not-insanely-inefficient range syntax. If converting to `Int` doesn't actually help you do that, just write the least-bad implementation of `toEnum` and `fromEnum` you can think of, and implement the other methods in terms of something else. The usual way to achieve "correctly defined" `Enum` instances is `deriving Enum` where that is applicable; if it isn't you almost always will have to override more than just the claimed minimal methods, unfortunately.

---

<sup>2</sup> If we were designing from scratch a class to support the range syntax today I think we probably wouldn't expose `toEnum` and `fromEnum` at all, we'd instead try to specify the minimal requirements for computing and applying deltas, probably requiring an associated type family (or multi-parameter class) allowing the type used for the delta to be different in each instance. Such a class simply couldn't have been written when `Enum` was designed, as the compiler features did not exist.

And I think we would use separate class for the bare minimum of enumerability that is `succ` and `pred` (or even `succ` on its own), and find a way of avoiding them being partial. I can imagine types where you can always generate the next element, but can't efficiently jump through a range in fixed increments, so perhaps if you just provide `succ` then `[x..]` would work, or even `[x..y]` if you also have `Eq`, but not `[x, y .. z]`.

I haven't really thought it through very hard, but I doubt it would end up looking very much like `Enum`.